# When I always get the same place in a race, can my end position differ

Tags: statistics

## Premise

Let's say I take part in a competition. There are `n` participants in the competition. There are no eliminations or anything between rounds in the competition. The person who finishes first in the competition gets `n` points, the second gets `n-1` and so on. The sum of the points determines the final position.

## Question

When I always finish in place $x \in [2, n-1]$ (second to second to last), can my final position be different than `x`?

Comment: How many rounds?  Any number?  Consider the following race results shown by the number of points each respective player gets: $(1,2,3,4,5),(3,2,4,5,1),(4,2,5,1,3),(5,2,1,3,4)$.  The second player always ended in second to last place in each individual race and so ended with a total score of $8$.  All other players however ended with a total score of $13$.  Our player who ended every race in second to last place came in overall dead last with all other players tying for first (*or tying for second to last if preferred*).

Comment: @JMoravitz i didn't think of the number of rounds... But your example is good. Can it also happen with more of a mid fields situation? For example, i always become 5th out of 10 and i end up 4th?

Comment: $(a,b,c,d,e,f),(b,d,c,e,f,a),(d,e,c,f,a,b),(e,f,c,a,b,d),(f,a,c,b,d,e)$  contestant $a$ finishes 3rd every time but 1st overall with $20$ points while everyone else has $17$.

Comment: If you're always 5th out of ten, you can end up 1st.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ahh, great, thanks. If these two comments are made into an answer, I can accept it

Comment: Now... if you are always in the middle position out of an odd number of positions... you can prove that either *everyone* ties for first or you do not end in first based on an argument involving everyone's average score.

Comment: Similarly, based on an argument involving averages, if you finish in the strictly bottom half in every individual race, you cannot be in first for the overall result.  So, if you are always 6th out of ten, you can *not* end up in 1st.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the top half in each contest, even if you're at the very bottom of the top half, you can still be first overall. I'll just give an example, with six contestants and five contests: if the six contestants finish (,,,,,),(,,,,,),(,,,,,),(,,,,,),(,,,,,) then $c$ is third (bottom of top half) in each contest but wins overall, $20$ points to $17$ for everyone else.